# update my sql database from form

Tags: php, mysql, forms

Hi I'm very new to php & slq coding .. I have being looking and tring everything to be able to update my php database ..

Here is what I have coded so fair .. This shows the fields of my database in a forum

```
   <?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="mixfm_djs"; // Mysql username 
$password="0121do1"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="mixfm_djs"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="table1"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
?>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="index.php">
  <table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
      <td><form name="form1" method="post" action="update_ac.php"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3">
        <tr>
          <td colspan="4"><strong>List data from mysql </strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="center"><strong>DJ-Name</strong></td>
          <td align="center"><strong>Password</strong></td>
          <td align="center"><strong>State</strong></td>
          <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
?>
        <tr>
          <td><input name="djname" type="text" id="djname" value="<? echo $rows['djname']; ?>" /></td>
          <td><input name="name" type="text" id="name" value="<? echo $rows['name']; ?>" size="15" /></td>
          <td><input name="state" type="text" id="state" value="<? echo $rows['state']; ?>" size="15" /></td>
          <td align="center">&nbsp;</td>
        </tr>
        <?php
}
?>
      </table></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <p>
    <input type="submit" name="update" id="update" value="update" />
  </p>
  <?php
mysql_close();
?>
</form>
```

Hope someone can help

Thanks

Comment: You haven't told us what your problem is, nor have you asked a question.

Comment: You only have a SELECT in there,how do you expect to update anything?Also mysql is deprecated,use mysqli or PDO.http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Comment: The code here how show the database in its fields.. I tring to get it so when I change a the text in the form box and click update .. It updates the database .. So saved the changes ..

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the comments, you should be using mysqli if you are really dedicated to mysql. Here is a little intro into using mysqli.

http://codular.com/php-mysqli

Secondly, you need an update statement in order to actually 'update' you mysql database. Here is a tutorial about updating using the mysqli extension.

http://www.pontikis.net/blog/how-to-use-php-improved-mysqli-extension-and-why-you-should

And a lot of people here will tell you to use mysqli or pdo for database stuff here, because mysql_query leaves your database open for some serious security flaws, and makes your code much less maintainable.

Since you are just starting out, you should definitely learn more about mysqli, pdo and prepared statements, because bad habits will be hard to break later on once you get used to using certain tools.

Comment: It's not that it's hard, it's that with PHP there are so many ways to do it wrong. While we could answer your question directly, we would be leading you down the wrong path, so it's hard to just give you an answer that isn't going to be beneficial in the long run.